# call plugin from plugin in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am using zf2 and I have created a few plugins that I can call from any controller in any plugin (so, no problem with that).
To do so, in the controller where the plugin is, I have added this to the module.config.php

```
'controler_plugins' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'myplugin' => 'MyModule\Controller\Plugin\MyPlygin'
    ),
),
```

So, with that my plugin is accessible from every controller with juste $this->myplugin().

My problem is that I can't call a plugin from a plugin in another module.
Any idea how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with plugins per se, but to me this sounds like a simple dependency injection matter? Instead of `invokables` make it a `factories` and inject plugin B into plugin A?

Answer (score 5):

Every plugin contains a reference to the controller it was called from, so you should be able to call any registered plugin from within another plugin like so:

```
$this->getController()->myplugin();
```